# ¿Como validar un datetime con date en una consulta php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Quiero validar las entradas y salidas de un sin numero personas en el día, es decir contar cuantas personas han entrado, cuantas han salido. para ello tengo un campo llamado `fecha_entrada` y `fecha_salida` (ambos campos son datetime), la idea como ya lo mencione es validar cuantos han entrado y salido en el día pero necesito específicamente la fecha (Y-m-d) sin colocar la hora:

**CODIGO:**

```
$cant_peoples = 
  $this->db->select('count(*) as in_company')
  ->from('company')
  ->where('entry_date', date('Y-m-d'))
  ->where('entry_date !=', '' )
  ->get()
  ->row();
```

> El problema esta en que este, internamente me tira un 0, y no se si
>   es porque no es posible validar un date con datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí es posible comparar  DATE con DATETIME, pero nunca se cumplirá la condición. El retorno de la consulta siempre será NULL.
Esta seria la consulta:

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as in_company');
$this->db->from('company');
$this->db->where('DATE(entry_date)',  date('Y-m-d'));
$this->db->where('entry_date !=', '' );
$query = $this->db->get();
$res= $query->result();
```

Comment: Excelente Men, Gracias.